# Script still runs after stopped browser

Tags: php, linux

I make a fetching script to get data from web pages. It saves some data to a mysql database.
When I hit stop or close the browser I see through phpmyadmin that it still adds records to infinity.

I killed the process many times but I cant figure out what is wrong to fix it.

Is it script's fault or server's ?

EDIT :
I close the browser i close my pc and the script still runs at the server.
Its not the code or the script.

Comment: Pretty vague.  Show the code you're using to save the data back at the database.

Comment: I'm sorry my crystal ball tells me your servers are stuck in an infinite time loop, caused by the butterfly effect forced from the user clicking his stop button. (a.k.a. we can't tell you until you give us exact details, such as your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```